# Request help with IBM Serial Parallel USB Adapter

Tags: 14.04

I am in the earliest stages of CCNA certification and I've decided to make it harder on myself by using Ubuntu; an OS that I have very little experience with.

The install went flawlessly and so far I'm loving some Ubuntu!!!

I have a device that attached to my PC via USB called an IBM USB Serial Parallel Adapter.  This device is necessary for me to connect to a Cisco router's Console (serial) port.

So I go into PuTTy and I don't know how to configure it to tell it that the serial commands get to the adapter via a specific USB port.  In Win 7, there's a drop down in PuTTy that lists the Serial Adapter on a given USB port, but there's no equivalent in the Ubuntu/Linux version of PuTTy.

I've tried to research the issue myself and learned a little about the lsusb command and even tried to substitute some of the info from a lusb -D command into PuTTy but with no luck.

I then tried to find Linux drivers for the device with no luck.

Also, if there's something silly I did not do, please call it out so I can help myself and potentially others in the future!!!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-connection) at section 4.26.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to launch PuTTy with sudo; specifically, "sudo putty" from a term window.